# Parasite Combination Inheritance: How does parent prototype's clone consist child prototype's property which has not been assigned yet?

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

Please look at the code snippet from Nicholas C. Zakas's book Professional JS for Web Developers:

```
function object(o){
  function F(){}
  F.prototype = o;
  return new F();
}

function inheritPrototype(subType, superType){
  var prototype = object(superType.prototype);
  console.log(prototype);
  prototype.constructor = subType;
  subType.prototype = prototype;
}

function SuperType(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.colors = [“red”, “blue”, “green”];
}

SuperType.prototype.sayName = function(){
  alert(this.name);
};

function SubType(name, age){
  SuperType.call(this, name);
  this.age = age;
}

inheritPrototype(SubType, SuperType);


SubType.prototype.sayAge = function(){
  alert(this.age);
};
```

In the function inheritPrototype(), I have logged **variable prototype**. I see that sayAge() is a property of **variable prototype**. I am unsure as to how sayAge property got assigned to prototype when I have assigned it to object(supertype.prototype). Also, SubType.prototype.sayAge is being initialized after I call the function inheritPrototype. So I am quite confused to see prototype having sayAge as it's property.

https://jsfiddle.net/shettyrahul8june/ed22rrnj/

Check the developer console after running it in JSFiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just how the console works. When you log an object with `console.log` in most implementations (esp. browser implementations), it logs a *reference* to the object. When you expand the object later, you see the properties it has *then*, when you expand it, not what it had when it was logged.

If we log the properties the object has **when you log it**, we can see that it doesn't get `sayAge` until later:

```js
function object(o) {
  function F() {}
  F.prototype = o;
  return new F();
}

function inheritPrototype(subType, superType) {
  var prototype = object(superType.prototype);
  showProps("in inheritPrototype", prototype);
  prototype.constructor = subType;
  subType.prototype = prototype;
}

function SuperType(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.colors = [1, 2, 3];
}

SuperType.prototype.sayName = function() {
  alert(this.name);
};

function SubType(name, age) {
  SuperType.call(this, name);
  this.age = age;
}

inheritPrototype(SubType, SuperType);


SubType.prototype.sayAge = function() {
  alert(this.age);
};
showProps("after assigning sayAge", SubType.prototype);

function showProps(msg, obj) {
  var propNames = Object.keys(obj);
  console.log(msg, "count: " + propNames.length, propNames.join(", "));
}
```

Comment: If you wanted to see it at the exact time, you'd need to make a deep clone and print that somehow.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the explanation T.J.